# Debian/Gnome stop auto-open of mounted volumes

Tags: linux, mount, gnome3, debian-wheezy

Since upgrading from Debian stable to Debian testing, every time I issue a `mount` command from the terminal, the file manager opens a window to the mounted path, interfering with my scripts (volume is in use for a split second).

I can't figure out how to disable Gnome's auto-opening of a file manager window for mounted volumes..

Answer (score 0):

it does what you want for the current session:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.. The command executes successfully, but an attempt to open the file manager to the mounted path persists.